# How to change Magento 2 Admin URL from admin dashboard

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-url

I want to change the admin URL by using custom admin URL and path

Answer (score 2):

- Go to **`Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin -> Admin Base URL`**.
- Uncheck the "**Use System value**" for "**Use Custom admin path**".
- Select "**Yes**" in "**Use Custom admin path**".
- A new field should appear called "**Custom Admin Path**". Fill in the value you need here. **For example:** if you put in `new_admin`, you will be able to login in the admin at the URL `http://www.example.com/new_admin`.

Comment: It worked, but if I want to add a Custom URL then what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-adminurl.html)

In Magento installation folder run this commande line :

`php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="THE_NEW_ADMIN_KEY"`

And then check with :

`php bin/magento info:adminuri`

Comment: I know that but I want to do it from the Admin Panel.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer (Using Magento 2 Admin settings):**

1. Log in the Magento 2 Admin interface
2. Click Stores
3. Click Configurations
4. In the panel on the left, under Advanced, click Admin and expand the Admin Base URL section Set Use Custom Admin Path to “Yes”.
5. Enter the Custom Admin Path. The path that you enter is appended to the
6. Custom Admin URL after the last forward slash. For example: `testadmin`
7. You will be logged out and redirected to the new Admin URL